# Viewmodel loses some of it's values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if there's already an answer to this question, but I couldn't find it.

When submitting a form, my `ViewModel` loses some of it's values. Specifically it's the error object that loses it's values. And I don't understand why. I don't have anything that should overwrite it. I'm very greateful for any help I can get.

I tried removing the `= new ...()`, but that makes the program throw the error

> not and instance of an object

ViewModel:

```cs
namespace Vacation.ViewModels
{
    public class EditScheduleViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public EditScheduleError Error { get; set; } = new EditScheduleError();
        public string GotoSched { get; set; } = "";
        public string GotoURL { get; set; } = "";
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
        public bool isLast { get; set; } = false;
        public User Employee { get; set; } = new User();
        public int TotalWeeks { get; set; } = 2;
        public Schedule ScheduleActive { get; set; } = new Schedule();
        public DateTime LastSchedEndDate { get; set; }
        public List<Schedule> ScheduleAll { get; set; } = new List<Schedule>();
        public List<ScheduleDay> Days { get; set; } = new List<ScheduleDay>(new ScheduleDay[28]);
        public List<int> ClinicIds { get; set; } = new List<int>(new int[28]);
        public List<ClinicInfo> ClinicsList { get; set; } = new List<ClinicInfo>();

        public EditScheduleViewModel ()
        {
            ProjectName = "Scheman";
        }
    }

    public class EditScheduleError
    {
        public bool Overlaps { get; set; }
        public EditScheduleOverlappingError OverlappingError { get; set; } = new EditScheduleOverlappingError();
    }

    public class EditScheduleOverlappingError
    {
        public bool OverlapsBefore { get; set; }
        public bool OverlapsAfter { get; set; }
        public int IdBefore { get; set; }
        public int IdAfter { get; set; }
        public EditScheduleOverlappingErrorResolutions Resolution { get; set; } = new EditScheduleOverlappingErrorResolutions();
    }

    public class EditScheduleOverlappingErrorResolutions
    {
        public bool ChangeThis { get; set; }
        public bool ChangeOther { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSchedule(EditScheduleViewModel editScheduleViewModel)
{
    if (editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.Resolution.ChangeOther == true) {
        if (editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.OverlapsBefore) {
            Schedule schedBefore = Db.Schedule.Where(x => x.Id == editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.IdBefore).Single();
            schedBefore.EndDate = editScheduleViewModel.ScheduleActive.StartDate.AddDays(-1);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
        if (editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.OverlapsAfter) {
            Schedule schedAfter = Db.Schedule.First(x => x.Id == editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.IdAfter);
            schedAfter.StartDate = editScheduleViewModel.ScheduleActive.EndDate.Value.AddDays(1);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }
    } else if (editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.Resolution.ChangeThis == true) {
        if (editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.OverlapsBefore) {
            Schedule schedBefore = Db.Schedule.AsNoTracking().First(x => x.Id == editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.IdBefore);
            editScheduleViewModel.ScheduleActive.StartDate = schedBefore.EndDate.Vƒalue.AddDays(1);
        }
        if (editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.OverlapsAfter) {
            Schedule schedAfter = Db.Schedule.AsNoTracking().First(x => x.Id == editScheduleViewModel.Error.OverlappingError.IdAfter);
            editScheduleViewModel.ScheduleActive.EndDate = schedAfter.StartDate.AddDays(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

That's not the whole part of the controller... do you need more?

The expected behaviour is for Error to keep it's values, even after i've submitted the form.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HttpPost method where you are reading the values.

Comment: Can you share the codes of the View and Controller? Also you do not need to initialize the properties of the EditScheduleViewModel.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal I've added the httppost method. I hope that it's enough. Or do you want more? It's quite a big method if you want the whole method.

Comment: For a ViewModel property to retain value after form submit, you need to have a field of that property on your form or you can put the existing ViewModel in some tempdata and retain it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding this to the view it worked! I had to set the values for some reason... unsure why. But hey, as long as it works, right? :)

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyError.Overlaps, new { @Value = Model.MyError.Overlaps })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyError.OverlappingError.OverlapsAfter, new { @Value = Model.MyError.OverlappingError.OverlapsAfter })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyError.OverlappingError.OverlapsBefore, new { @Value = Model.MyError.OverlappingError.OverlapsBefore })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyError.OverlappingError.IdAfter, new { @Value = Model.MyError.OverlappingError.IdAfter })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyError.OverlappingError.IdBefore, new { @Value = Model.MyError.OverlappingError.IdBefore })
```